# Spring Boot started throwing MBeans Exception after upgrade to Yosemite

Tags: spring-boot, osx-yosemite

I upgraded today to MAC OS X Yosemite, and started running my earlier running Spring-Boot-Application, it started loading, but it suddenly failed to start. I went through logs and found that the application ran twice (Actually i found that from Spring banner). I cleared logs ran the app again, and again it did the same throwing error of can't register mbeans, it is already registered. I went through all my other apps, and all thrown the same error. I ran apps on Pivotal Server, Apache Tomcat, and also as Spring Boot app and also made sure that I'm not running any instance before. Is there a bug due to Yosemite as earlier everything was just fine with Mavericks.

Cannot post log here as it is more than 30000 chars which is upper limit of SO post.

Attaching log as pastebin link. http://pastebin.com/eAQdHfRy

Comment: Perhaps you could post the log as a Gist (https://gist.github.com) or on a service like Pastebin (http://pastebin.com)?